# C++ Function Comment/Contract

Tags: c++

Hi I do learn C++ at University, but noone teached us how to correctly comment our code. I think code readability is very important.

So now my Question: Do I have to write my Function/Method Contract/Comment to my function declaration or implementation?

Example:

**sort.h**

```
class Sort{
    public:
        /**
        * Simple Bubble Sort algorithm
        *
        * @param list vector of strings to sort
        * @return sorted vector of strings
        */
        static std::vector<std::string> bubbleSort(std::vector<std::string> list);
};
```

**sort.cpp**

```
#include "sort.h"

/**
* Simple Bubble Sort algorithm
*
* @param list vector of strings to sort
* @return sorted vector of strings
*/
std::vector<std::string> Sort::bubbleSort(std::vector<std::string> list){
    //Do anything
}
```

Which Commet is correct?

Comment: Paraphrasing Uncle Bob: The best comment is no comment at all. If you don't have obligation to write them, just avoid it and write code that is self-explanatory. Much more readable than large blocks of comments.

Comment: Make your code do the explaining.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen _"just avoid it and write code that is self-explanatory"_ That's just a dream, and never became true in my (long) experience. There's nothing wrong with a well documented interface.

Comment: Why is the `bubbleSort` inside a class `Sort`? Can't it be put inside a `namespace`? Namespaces are the idiomatic way in C++ to group free functions together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the major reference and interface for others to use your code is the header file, you should place your comments primarily there.

---

<sub>However, someone who needs to maintain your implementation code later won't be unhappy to find a shorter descriptive comment what the function does in the implementation as well (without need to look back into the header file).</sub>

Comment: Comment duplication is just as bad for maintenance as code duplication.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, it's easy to maintain, since if you change something in the header, you probably need to do changes in the implementation, and when doing so, you can simply copy and overwrite the comment in the implementation file as well. Though I personally don't like implementation files littered with documentation comments.

Comment: Your whole argument was that maintenance could be done without opening the header file.  I agree header changes are easy to copy to the implementation, but that's still extra work, and the reverse is not so easy if the header file is not even being opened.  Clones will always result in divergence sooner or later.

Comment: @Ben I changed that part a bit. I Wasn't really thinking of clones in 1st place.